# Sync worker task and progress view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency, swift5

I'm refactoring/rewriting some code in a legacy app where a (sometimes) long running query is made. A custom view controller is used to show progress and when the query is complete another view controller for the result is shown.

The current code presents the progress VC, then starts a task for the query and when the query is complete it presents the result VC. The problem is that the progress VC is dismissed "automatically" when the query task posts a success notification through Notification Center. Needless to say, this is not very stable and many times the progress VC is not dismissed in time before the result VC is presented, resulting in a stern log print from iOS and no result VC.

To avoid large changes to the code (for now) I have changed it so the progress VC is fully controlled from the context that presents it. But I still need to wait for it to be fully presented before it can be dismissed and that needs to be synchronized with the query, which may execute faster than the presentation time.

To wrap it up, this is my current idea, but I'm not really happy with having a separate Task just for syncing. In a "normal" concurrency environment I would use a binary semaphore or similar, is there a cleaner solution in Swift?  I'm looking for a way to signal to the Task that the completion handler for the `present()`-method has been called.

```
let t = Task {
    // Wait longer than present(animated: true) time
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000_000)
}

let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Progress", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: { t.cancel() })

Task {
    // Perform work that may take less or more time than presentation
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000)
    
    // Wait until alert is fully presented (no wait if work time was long enough)
    let _ = await t.result

    // Cleanup
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    // Present work result view controller
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think some additional informations are needed here, but maybe you could use a continuation and store it in the destination view controller.